# I have installed React on my remote desktop and developed a web page. How do I go about doing the same on production server?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react.js. 
I intsalled node and react on my remote desktop and developed web page with local ajax files.

Do I have to follow the same steps on my production server or I can directly push the changes(i.e. react files) to prod?
As far as my local files are concerned like App.js, index.html,ajax files, images I can push them after my prod setup right?

Another concern :
For my local files I have to prepend my localhost port number to my url.
How can I get rid of it?
For ex:

In my ajax calls I am using data type as jsonp for cross domain calls and also set cross domain to true. The ajax call works but I have to mention the localhost port number in my ajax url.

Instead of http://localhost:7070/reactapp/app/components/ajax/insertData.php I would want it to be-> react-app/app/components/ajax/insertData.php, so it can work on my production server.
See below for code.

```
 addData()
    {
        $.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
   url:"http://localhost:7070/reactapp/app/components/ajax/insertData.php",
            data: 
         {inQueue:this.state.inQTxt,totEmails:this.state.totalEmailsTxt},

            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(result) {

            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {

            }.bind(this)
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the npm steps to put in on production

For URL Generator, You can use something simple like

https://codesandbox.io/embed/intelligent-galois-7edwe